# Georeferencing declassified CORONA images of coastlines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, orthophoto

I'm trying to georeference declassified [CORONA](http://www.nro.gov/history/csnr/corona/) images of coastlines in order to asses coastline changes and human impact.

In most case, georeferencing is easy, but since images of coastlines can only have GCP's inland of the object of interest (in rare occasions, islands an artificial features seaward), namely, shore line and strip of coastal sands, there will be inherent georeferencing errors.

How can I minimize errors?

I've thought of two options, but have yet to try them:

1. Georeferencing long swathes of coastline at a time (roughly 2Km long by 200m wide) with a linear/1st order equation (Corona images aren't orthorectified), so any localized errors will have minute effect on the outcome. possible problems: not enough GCP in 200 meters wide coastal area.
2. Short swathes of coastline (roughly 5oom * 1Km), thus probably increasing the potential GCP's inland and reducing local errors. possible problems: cumulative error if I try to use one image as GCP for another.

The reason I am inclined to georeference one complete CORONA strip is to save space, and ease workload for my computer.

I am using ArcMap 10.2, and have a recent orthorectified high resolution image of the terrain

Comment: Are the images of roughly the same time? If possible georeference the 'easy' ones (with notable inland features) and then georeference the 'hard' ones to the already georeferenced 'easy' ones - if they are roughly the same time then you can use notable trees and other temporary objects to image-to-image georeference.